# add a custom RFC822 header via IMAP?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

Is there an easy way to add a custom RFC822 header to a message on an IMAP server with imaplib?

I am writing a python-based program that filters my IMAP mail store. When I did this with Procmail I had the option of adding headers. But there doesn't seem to be a way to do that with the Python imap implementation.

Specifically, I want to add a custom header like:

```
X-VY32-STATUS: Very Cool
```

So that it appears in the mail headers:

```
 To: vy32@stackoverflow.com
 From: Yo@mama.com
 Subject: Test Message
 X-VY32-STATUS: Very Cool

 The regular message is down here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better option would be to use **custom server flags** called keywords.

A keyword is defined by the server implementation. Keywords do not begin with "\".  Servers MAY permit the client to define new keywords in the mailbox.

To add myflag to the message you can use

```
STORE number +FLAGS (myflag)
```

to search:

```
SEARCH KEYWORD myflag
```

Bear in mind that some servers don't allow custom flags.

Comment: But I'm not sure that the Apple Mail client lets me access the flags.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple Mail client does not let me access the flags. However, you are correct, this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [RFC 2060](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2060.html) allows the edit of received mail headers. If you want to edit the mail response header this can be done with the `email` package.

Comment: So my only option is to download the header, modify it, and send it back?

Comment: Procmail is a mail delivery agent. The IMAP protocol is used to transfer the mails form a mail server and not for editing mails on the server.

Comment: Yes, I know that procmail is a delivery agent. But increasingly we are running with mailservers that are only accessible by IMAP. It would be nice to have procmail-like functionality from a python script running on a client somewhere. There are some systems that do this (not particularly well, I might add). Right now they don't have the ability to update the mail headers. There would be a nice way to do that. You can do it with IMAP by downloading the entire message and then writing it back, but that's not very efficient.