# Python script to add a header to an email on an imap server

Tags: python, macos, email, imap

I want to write a python small script to tag my emails in a way that does not depend on a mail client. My idea is to add a custom header X-TAG: ... to the email. Also I want to use this with popfile.

My mails are stored on an imap server. So I am looking for a script which would take a message uid, use imaplib to retrieve the message, convert it somehow to something the email lib understands, add the custom header (about the only thing I know how to do), and then use imaplib again to store it back to the imap server.

Does this work? And does anyone know of a script that does it?

(I have read the related question [add a custom RFC822 header via IMAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575805/add-a-custom-rfc822-header-via-imap)) but it refers to procmail which I don't use.

PS: I want to use the same approach to permanently decrypt emails later, hence the very general approach using python.

Comment: "Permanently decrypt emails later" sounds like you are trying to persist changes to IMAP. I don't believe it works like that. You can add custom headers to messages you send a read headers from messages you receive.

Comment: IMAP messages are immutable.  You'd end up downloading the message, mutating it, and uploading a copy.  Could you use a custom \FLAG instead?

Comment: And why do you want to use IMAP instead of server-side filtering?  The proper place to do message filtering/changing is on reception, not later via a retrieval protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I’d be ok with downloading, changing and uploading as long as the essential headers and info is not changed, i.e. from, subject, date received etc. This is only for my own book keeping and long term storage. I don’t know how \FLAGs work. Are these independent of the server software? And will they be preserved when I store the email on my disk?

Comment: Max: I don’t control the server. It is a university wide exchange server and I can’t filter anything there. What I want is something that is stored in the message itself, so that I can search for it on any of my devices, even on my phone. And even in 20 years from now.